# How to Calculate no_of_days between to datepickers in Laravel onchange

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have this Laravel-5.8 code:

Controller

```
public function store(StoreLeaveRequestRequest $request)
{
    if (! Gate::allows('leave_request_create')) {
        return abort(401);
    }
try {   
        $commencementDate   = Carbon::parse($request->commencement_date);
        $resumptionDate     = Carbon::parse($request->resumption_date);
        $leaverequest = HrLeaveRequest::create([
            'leave_type_id'             => $request->leave_type_id,
            'commencement_date'         => $commencementDate,
            'resumption_date'           => $resumptionDate,               
        ]);
        Session::flash('success', 'Leave Request is created successfully');
        return redirect()->route('service.leave_requests.index');
    } 
    catch (Exception $exception) 
    {
        Session::flash('error', 'Action failed!');
        return redirect()->route('service.leave_requests.index');  
    }        
}
```

Also I have this create.blade code

```
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Commencement Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="commencement_date" value="{{old('commencement_date')}}"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->firstOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}" max="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->lastOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div>                    
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Resumption Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="resumption_date" value="{{old('resumption_date')}}"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->firstOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}" max="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->lastOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div> 
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Requested Days:</label>
                <input  type="number" name="no_of_days" class="form-control" value="{{old('no_of_days')}}" style="width: 100%;" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function () {
            $('#commencement_date').datetimepicker({
                format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
            });
            $('#resumption_date').datetimepicker({
                format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I want to achieve is that, onchange in resumption_date, I want to subtract

> commencement_date from resumption_date and load the result in no_of_days

Comment: which datetimepicker library you are using? can you share a link?

Comment: @AndySong - Its  jQuery UI Datepicker:        <script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>


        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function () {
                $('#commencement_date').datetimepicker({
                    format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
                });
                $('#resumption_date').datetimepicker({
                    format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
                });
            });
        });
 </script>

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: No. I have not solved it. I was just planning trying to use other means of solving it